# How can I redirect the same message to both stdoud and stderr (without temporary object)

Tags: shell, ksh, stdout, stderr

It is easy to redirect stdout or stderr to the same output (file or one of the 2 std output) with a `1>&1`,`>&2` and/or `>file`.
Is there a way to send the same output to both the std output in KSH (like | tee File but with &2 as file) ?
I try to have the stream to stdout AND on stderr at the same time (duplicate the output, one on each channel) but without using temporary object (variable or file)

I use a temporary variable but try to avoid this

```
Tempo="$(
   #all my code with output to stdout and stderr
   )"
echo "${Tempo}"
echo "${Tempo}" >&2
```

Question asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841484/how-can-i-redirect-the-same-message-to-both-stdoud-and-stderr-without-temporary) with suggestion to ask it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system doesn't have `/dev/stderr`, you can use `perl` that way:

```
{
  your-code
  ..
} | perl -pe 'print STDERR'
```

`perl` processes the input one line at a time, so you won't see partial lines there. For instance with code like:

```
printf 'Foo'; sleep 2; printf 'Bar\n'
```

You'll only see `FooBar` after 2 seconds.

Also note that some commands buffer their output when it doesn't go to a terminal, so that may affect the way the output is done.

Comment: KSH/AIX does not accept /dev/stderr if not available `awk: 0602-575 Cannot find or open file /dev/stderr.
 The input line number is 1.
 The source line number is 1.`. Same problem as a direct redirection in this case.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought to remember that was a POSIX requirement, but it's not. I switched to `perl` which is going to be more reliable anyway as it will support NUL bytes in the input.

Comment: yep, with perl it works and I keep the 2 channel for any following action if needed

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether `ksh` has a feature to do that. `zsh` can do it (with the `multios` feature).

But there is a way with `tee`:

```
echo foo | tee /dev/stderr
echo foo | tee /proc/self/fd/2
```

Comment: good idea the /dev/stderr but it failed on may KSH (also with -a)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Interesting. Isn't that Linux? What is the output of `ls -l /dev/stderr`? Does the second option work?

Comment: On Linux, you want `tee -a /dev/stderr` as if stderr is going to a file, that file would be truncated otherwise. Other Unices that support /dev/stderr don't have that problem. Note that `/proc/self/fd/2` is Linux specific.

Comment: `ls: 0653-341 The file /dev/stderr does not exist.` (AIX /KSH)

Comment: I have a `/dev/tty` that can be used so `echo "hello" | tee -a  /dev/tty 1>&2` do the job. The only point seems that nothing can be treated after from stdin (send to tty not streamed) so it "should" be the last instruction (for stdin entry)